# Why is include? throwing an argument error?

Tags: ruby, arguments

This is a snippet from a larger chunk of code:

```
print "> "
$next_move = gets.chomp

case $next_move.include?
when "instructions"
  puts "$next_move is instructions"
else
  puts "$next_move is NOT instructions"
end
```

Everytime I run it in the terminal, whether I'm using ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3, or 2.0.0, I get the following error:

```
test.rb:4:in `include?': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
from test.rb:4
```

This code worked last night on a different computer.

Isn't `include?` checking the contents of that global variable? What other argument should I be passing to it?

I'm kinda stumped here, especially since all I did was move the code from one computer to another.

Comment: "This code worked last night on a different computer." err... no. :-) Likely, `case "next_move".include? "instructions"` did, or `case "next_move" when "instructions"`.

Comment: Be very careful using globals: `$next_move`. They are seldom needed in Ruby code, and, the majority of the time, are a warning sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @tinman, thanks. I've since improved my coding to avoid them. This is an exercise from a few weeks ago that still has me puzzled. Even though Denis doesn't believe me, honestly, all I did was run the code on a different computer and all of a sudden things that worked no longer seem to work...

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-include-3F

> Returns true if str contains the given string or character.

That means it requires exactly 1 argument, so no wonder it throws ArgumentError when called without arguments.

So the code should be:

```
if $next_move.include? 'instructions'
  puts '$next_move is instructions'
else
  puts '$next move is NOT instructions'
end
```

Comment: "Besides, you call include? not on string contained in next_move variable, but on the string 'next_move'." Huh? How does that work? How am I NOT calling on the contents of the variable?

Comment: You did it in the first version of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something had to have changed between the two computers you tested this on.  If you are wanting to use this as a case statement, you probably had something along the lines of:

```
next_move = 'instructions'

case next_move
when "instructions"
  puts "$next_move is instructions"
else
  puts "$next_move is NOT instructions"
end
```

This specifically tests if `next_move` IS instructions. As an if/else statement:

```
if next_move.include? 'instructions'
  puts "$next_move is instructions"
else
  puts "$next_move is NOT instructions"
end
```

See [eval.in](https://eval.in/33059) for more information.